# Error deploying asmx project to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, asmx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created an asmx webservice using VS2013 and want to deploy it in Elastic Beanstalk, but I'm receiving next error:

```
Deployment of the web site failed due to errors during build of the deployment archive.
Check Visual Studio's Output window 'Build' and/or 'Amazon Web Services' panes for more detail.
```

And this is my AWSToolkit log:

```
2014-05-20 16:39:24,816 [49] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.AWSToolkitPackage - Output to AWS output window pane: Commencing deployment for project WS/MyWS
2014-05-20 16:39:24,816 [49] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.AWSToolkitPackage - Commencing deployment for project WS/MyWS
2014-05-20 16:39:25,405 [5] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.AWSToolkitPackage - Output to AWS output window pane: ...building deployment package C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\AWSDeploy.2dddeee5
2014-05-20 16:39:25,405 [5] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.AWSToolkitPackage - ...building deployment package C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\AWSDeploy.2dddeee5
2014-05-20 16:39:25,405 [5] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.Shared.VSWebProjectInfo - EnvDTEProject.FullName lookup yielded 'http://localhost:60047/MyWS'
2014-05-20 16:39:25,405 [5] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.Shared.VSWebProjectInfo - Detected VS2012 HTTP-based path for website project, 'FullPath' properties lookup yielded 'D:\dev\WS\MyWS'
2014-05-20 16:39:25,405 [5] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.Shared.VSWebProjectInfo - Website project location lookup final yield is D:\dev\WS\MyWS\
2014-05-20 16:39:25,405 [5] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.AWSToolkitPackage - Output to AWS output window pane: ...caught exception during deployment package creation -
2014-05-20 16:39:25,421 [5] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.AWSToolkitPackage - Output to AWS output window pane: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.g:
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you use ReSharper?

Comment: I don't. I used to use it but I installed it some weeks ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My application was a web site and not a web application. 
After switching to a web application I could deploy in Beanstalk.